# Degree of splitting field of $x^3-5$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field

> Find the degree of the splitting field of $f(x):=x^3-5$ over $F:=\mathbb{F}_7$.

Attempt:

$f$ is irreduicible in $F[x]$ (suppose in contradiction it is reducible, thus it splits to at least one linear normalized polynomial element but this is contradiction beacuse $f$ has no roots in $F$). Thus, if $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$, we get $F\subset F(5^{1\over3})\subseteq E$. So I get that the degree is at least $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $[E:F]=2$ and $\alpha^3=5$ then there exists some polynomial $g$ of degree $2$ such that $g(\alpha)=0$. But then
$$f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$$
for some polynomials $q$ and $r$, and the degree of $r$ is at most $1$.
Therefore
$$0=f(\alpha)=q(\alpha)q(\alpha)+r(\alpha)=r(\alpha)$$
So $r=0$. This is a contradiction because $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Why does $|E:F|=2$ imply the existence of $g$?

Comment: It is the very definition of the degree of an extension.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $f(x)=x^3-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_7$ since it has no root.

Further reference:

[Splitting field of $x^3 - 2$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002405/splitting-field-of-x3-2-over-mathbbf-5?rq=1)

Comment: I noticed that but not sure how it helps.

Comment: And if $\alpha$ is one root then $\alpha^7$ is another...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $\omega$ is a root of $x^3-5$ in some extension (it has no root in $\mathbf F_7$), search for cube roots in $\mathbf F_7$. Deduce the splitting field is $\mathbf F_7[\omega]$.