# The splitting extention above Z_ (p)

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

F (x) is a polynomial on Z_ (p), and n is an irreducible polynomial.
When a is the root of f (x), is the splitting field of f (x) on Z_ (p)?

Using Frobunius automorphism we have found that a, a ^ p, ... a ^ (p ^ (n-1)) is also the root of f (x).
Since Z_ (p) is a perfect field, the splitting field of f (x) is also a separable extension.
I want to show that the splitting field of f (x) is Z_ (p) (a) because a, a ^ p, ..., a ^ (p ^ (n-1)
My guess is wrong or can you help me?
Thank you for your hlp!

Comment: You need to show that the other zeros are in $\Bbb{Z}_p(a)$. Can you manage that?

Comment: This is close to [being a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91178/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Lahtonen Thank you! Z_p (a) is a finite field finite field and can be separated and has different roots. But are there any reasons why we have different things?